# There is no is build for my phonegap project on build.phonegap.com

Tags: phonegap-build

I have built a Cordova project, and I have uploaded it to a Phonegap build, Android build appears on build tab but there is no Windows or iOS.

Below is the picture I get from build.phonegap.com

[image]

So how can I add iOS support to the project?
I have tried the following command in Cordova cli in my local machine

```
cordova platform -add ios
```

It runs successfully and adds iOS to the platform project. I uploaded files again to build.phonegap.com, but again no success in getting an iOS build tab.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap applications are configured using a config.xml file. This should be at the root of your application.

You can have zero or more of these elements present in your config.xml. Set the name attribute to one of ios, android, or windows. If you specify none, all platforms will be built. Example usage:

```
<platform name="ios" />
<platform name="android" />
<platform name="winphone" />
```

so i had to add below line to config.xml

```
<platform name="ios" />
```